# How can ESP32 retrieve a code stored in Amazon S3 database and execute it instantly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iot, esp32, aws-iot

As a part of my project, I am trying to integrate ESP32 with some of the AWS services.

One of the task demands to store certain codes(stored as '.ino' files) of ESP32(in Arduino IDE) in Amazon S3 buckets(cloud storage). Whenever the user(For example: a mobile app) or ESP32 itself sends requests to AWS S3 server to retrieve any .ino file, that particular .ino file should be received and executed instantaneously by ESP32.

While trying to figure out the solution for the above, I am stuck thinking about how exactly will ESP32  execute the code retrieved from cloud   while maintaining a web-socket connection with AWS Servers.

One of the possible solutions which I thought was using Dual Core Processing in ESP32 but I am not exactly sure how and where this would be used in my Arduino IDE code

It would be great if someone could throw some light on the above query!

Comment: This won't work, The `.ino` file is C++ code, which needs to be compiled before the ESP32 can execute it. The only way this might work is if the compiled code can be used to update the ESP over the air, but that is still not likely to be feasible.

Comment: You are dealing with an MCU without an OS, it doesn't have the ability to load a new app and run it. If you want to load a code and run it, you need a computer like a Raspberry Pi running a linux OS. Having said that, if you want to use ESP32, write your sketch in such a way, that you get the data(a flag, a name, etc.) from AWS to decide which part of the ESP32 code to execute.

Comment: This is a common lack of understanding on how an MCU works versus a microprocessor. A microprocessor run on an OS, it loads the program into RAM and execute it. An MCU does not load the program into RAM, it _run_ the code from flash memory and only load the data into the RAM.

Comment: To be clear, it doesn't have the ability to *compile* a new app and run it. It does have the ability to load a compiled binary and run that.